# Error:(12, 5) Original attribute defined here. Error:(466) Attribute already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-studio

Error:(12, 5) Original attribute defined here.    Error:(466) Attribute  already defined with incompatible format.

Comment: <declare-styleable name="ActionBar"><attr name="navigationMode"><enum name="normal" value="0"/><enum name="listMode" value="1"/><enum name="tabMode" value="2"/></attr><attr name="displayOptions"><flag name="none" value="0"/><flag name="useLogo" value="0x1"/><flag name="showHome" value="0x2"/><flag name="homeAsUp" value="0x4"/><flag name="showTitle" value="0x8"/><flag